# Как получить значения из словаря?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Столкнулась с такой проблемой. Программа должна выводить значение словаря, после введения нужно ключа.

Например: Я ввожу `Jack` 5 раз подряд,то на выходе я должна получить массив `[11, 11, 11, 11, 11]`. Но так не происходит, подскажите где я совершила ошибку и помогите исправить.

Заранее вас, очень-очень благодарю.

```
deck = {'2': 2, '3': 3, '4': 4, '5': 5,
        '6': 6, '7': 7, '8': 8, '9': 9, '10': 10,
        'Jack': 11, 'Queen': 12, 'King': 13, 'Ace': 14}


inputs = []

for i in range(5):
    inputs.append(input())
    print(inputs)
    if inputs == deck.keys():
        print(deck.values())
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
deck = {'2': 2, '3': 3, '4': 4, '5': 5,
        '6': 6, '7': 7, '8': 8, '9': 9, '10': 10,
        'Jack': 11, 'Queen': 12, 'King': 13, 'Ace': 14}
Res = []
for i in range(5):
    key = input()
    print(key)
    if key in deck:
        Res.append(deck[key])
print(Res)
```

Раз вам нужен на выходе массив, то этот способ будет лучше

Comment: Да, именно это и помогло. Благодарю.

Answer (score 2):

Используйте проверку с помощью [оператора `in`](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#dictionaries).
Обратите внимание, что проще значение, возвращаемое из [`input()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#input) присвоить в переменную:

```python
deck = {'2': 2, '3': 3, '4': 4, '5': 5,
        '6': 6, '7': 7, '8': 8, '9': 9, '10': 10,
        'Jack': 11, 'Queen': 12, 'King': 13, 'Ace': 14}

for i in range(5):
    key = input()
    print(key)
    if key in deck:
        print(deck[key])
```

Answer (score 1):

Ошибок несколько.

Вот здесь

```
if inputs == deck.keys():
```

вы сравниваете то, что ввели,  на равенство с ключами словаря. Ключи словаря выглядят примерно так:

```
['King', 'Ace', '10', 'Queen', '3', '2', '5', '4', '7', '6', '9', '8', 'Jack']
```

Понятно, что вы такое не вводили.

Вот здесь

```
print(deck.values())
```

вы хотите вывести ВСЕ значения, которые есть в словаре, а не только то, которое соответствует введенному ключу.

Остальное см. ответ @andrybak.